# Casting string to integer awk?

Tags: parsing, awk, gawk

I am parsing with awk an output file where in certain point  the date is displayed in this way

```
08/20/2014--05:08:48 PM--357624188
...
08/20/2014--05:10:04 PM--487503599
...
```

I would like to know whether is possible or not to convert the string date/time into a integer because I would like to calculate the MTBF based on that time.

May anyone tell me how to achieve that casting in awk/gawk?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards!

Edit: My output should be `357624188` as an integer so that I can suctract `487503599 - 357624188`

SOLVED: as @Kent was suggesting, I could solve it using

```
awk 'BEGIN {previousT=0}{print $NF " " previousT " " $NF - previousT; previousT=$NF;}'
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: My expected output would be something like `357624188` but I would like it to be a integer

Comment: @ndarkness `awk -F'--' '{print $NF}' file` ? :-)

Comment: ndarkness it might be better to write an answer with the solution, so that it is clear that it was solved to the future readers of the question. Also, you can ask @Kent to post it as an answer.

Comment: wrt your posted solution - you don't need to init previousT, you almost certainly do want a test so you don't print anything for the first line read, you don't need a trailing semi-colon, and you should use `,` instead of a hard-coded `" "` between output fields. e.g. `awk 'prev!=""{print $NF, prev, $NF-prev} {prev=$NF}'`.

Answer (score 3):

you can do in this way, (data validation ignored)

```
awk -F'--' '{printf "%d-%d=%d\n",$NF,p,$NF-p;p=$NF}' file
```

test

```
$ echo "08/20/2014--05:08:48 PM--111      
dquote> 08/20/2014--05:08:48 PM--211      
dquote> 08/20/2014--05:08:48 PM--311"|awk -F'--' '{printf "%d-%d=%d\n",$NF,p,$NF-p;p=$NF}'
111-0=111
211-111=100
311-211=100
```